# How to check if child element does not have a class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out how to check if a parent div has a child p element without a certain class.

So e.g.

```
    <div id="one" class="item">
        <p class="A"></p>
        <p class="B"></p>
        <p class="C"></p>
    </div>

    <div id="two" class="item">
        <p class="B"></p>
        <p class="C"></p>
    </div>
```

If the div does not have a p element with the class "A", I want to hide that div.

How would I do this?

I tried:

```
if (jQuery(".item > p.A").length <= 0){
    //run code here
}
```

but that does not seem to work

Thanks

Comment: use `.hasClass(  )` of jQuery  https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: implement `hasChild()`.

Comment: @badcode, sorry, see my updated answer. I initally misunderstood what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use jQuery [:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) like

```
$('div:not(:has(p.A))').hide();
```

```js
$('div:not(:has(p.A))').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="item">
        <p class="A">A</p>
        <p class="B">B</p>
        <p class="C">C</p>
    </div>

    <div id="two" class="item">
        <p class="B">B</p>
        <p class="C">C</p>
    </div>
```

**Or**, you can take an *iterative* approach

```
$('div').each(function() {
  if ($(this).has('p.A').length == 0) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```js
$('div').each(function() {

  if ($(this).has('p.A').length == 0) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one" class="item">
  <p class="A">A</p>
  <p class="B">B</p>
  <p class="C">C</p>
</div>

<div id="two" class="item">
  <p class="B">B</p>
  <p class="C">C</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @badcoder, dont forget to mark an answer as accepted to guide future readers of this post as to what happened

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this. In my opinion this describes better what you are doing and is easier when you read it back. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ayxdm7y3/

```
if ($('div').children().hasClass("A")){
   console.log("yes");
}
```